# can not convert type double to string using c#

Tags: c#

Am receiving this error Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'....i used the following code, what might be the problem? is there an easier way than mine?

```
QtyTextBox.Text = SimulateVal.Val(TextBox2.Text) + SimulateVal.Val(QtyTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Because using Google is too hard right? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Convert.ToString() method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
QtyTextBox.Text = (SimulateVal.Val(TextBox2.Text) + SimulateVal.Val(QtyTextBox.Text)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `SimulateVal.Val(string)` returns a double, as in a numeric type, and you want to output the sum of the two numbers as text.

`QtyTextBox.Text = (SimulateVal.Val(TextBox2.Text) + SimulateVal.Val(QtyTextBox.Text)).ToString();`